# DBUnit is not Compatible with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

I recently installed PHPUnit globally by downloading PHP Archive (PHAR) as per mentioned here
https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-9.html

I downloaded DBunit https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit by reading the readme.md from this github page and configured phpunit.xml as mentioned there but when I execute phpunit on cmd it says

`Extension: C:\my\project\path\dbunit.phar is not compatible with the version of PHPUnit.`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ???

Comment: [this can help you?](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit)

Comment: As mentioned in dbunit github, the package is no longer maintained. So you will have to install an older version of phpunit.

Comment: "you will have to install an older version of phpunit" is the wrong solution. The right solution is to rewrite the tests to not depend on DbUnit.